# Shiny Send plain string from server to ui

Tags: javascript, r, string, shiny

i'm facing an issue that probably is easy too solve but is bugging me.

I have a **global.R** script where I use JS to compute the screen height

```
jscode_for_screen_Height <- '$(document).on("shiny:connected", function(e) {
                             var jsHeight = screen.height; 
                             Shiny.onInputChange("GetScreenHeight",jsHeight); });'
```

This variable is used in several parts in my **server.R** and it works properly. E.g.

```
output$viewDataCTgov <- DT::renderDataTable({
DT::datatable(data_to_render_CTgov(),
options = list(scrollX = TRUE,scrollY = paste(input$GetScreenHeight,"px",sep=""), 
scrollCollapse=TRUE,pageLength =  100,searchHighlight = TRUE), escape = FALSE)
})
```

Now I'm creating a leaflet map and in **ui.R** I have

```
 leafletOutput("mymap", height = XXX )
```

leafletoutput accepts a string as height parameter (e.g. "400")

Here the problems:

1) I can't use  input$GetScreenHeight because i'm on the **ui.R** and input is not in the scope of the script.

2) I can't figure out how to pass a plain string to **ui.R** from the **server.R**

What I tried so far is to use in **server.R**

```
output$ScreenHeightvalue <- paste0(input$GetScreenHeight)
```

And in **ui.R**

```
leafletOutput("mymap", height =(textOutput("ScreenHeightvalue")))
```

but doesn't work due to the fact that textOutput("ScreenHeightvalue") is not a plain string.

How can I pass paste0(input$GetScreenHeight) from the **server.R** to the **ui.R** as plain string?

Comment: A simple way would be to use renderUI() : it's a function to create UI objects in the server. https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/renderUI.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to pass a plain string from server to ui, but you can define your lealfetOutput in the server by using a renderUI

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(-93.65, 42.0285, zoom = 17)
  })

  output$test <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      leafletOutput("myMap", height = paste0(input$GetScreenHeight))
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks! You are a lifesaver!